# Indices not in range, running LSTM model on sequence data

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I am new to Keras and Neural networks. I need to implement and LSTM model on my data set.

My data set consists of sequences like this:

52 53 54 55 66 67 58 59 60
68 69 70 58 59 60
68 71 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 72 73 5 6 7 74 75 10 11 12 13 14

...
I have 467 ".txt" files which keep sequences like this. Each file has variant number of sequences. The name of the file is the label for all sequences ( for example for file name "100026" the label for every single sequence is 100026).

So, I implemented this code that first pads sequences to the longest sequence. I was told that I have to use Masking after padding. I could not figure it out So changed lots of parts shown in comments but no luck yet.

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
#import numpy.ma as ma
#from keras import layers
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Masking
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.utils import to_categorical


nb_classes =467

def load_data():
    path = r'I:\NEDA\GNOME\Converted to ID'
    max_len= -1
    data =[]
    data_labels =[]
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        lbl = 0 # to convert the labels to integers starting from 0
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as f:
            lbl+=1
            for line in f:
                data.append(line.split())
                data_labels.append(lbl) #filename.split(".")[0]
                if max_len < len(line.split()):
                    max_len = len(line.split())

                #print(filename.split(".")[0])
    percent = int(len(data)*0.7) # 70% for training and 30% for testing
    data = np.array(data)
    nb_features= len(np.unique(data)) # extracting number of available features( functioons)

    #*data = pad_sequences(data, maxlen=max_len) ### np.expand_dim

    #data_labels=np.array(data_labels)
    #print(data.shape)
    train_data = data[0:percent]
    train_labels = data_labels[0:percent]    
    test_data = data[percent:]
    test_labels = data_labels[percent:]
    #print(train_set.shape) # + " " + train_labels.shape)
    return (np.array(train_data), np.array(train_labels), np.array(test_data), np.array(test_labels) , nb_features , max_len)

train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels, nb_features, max_len = load_data()
train_data = pad_sequences(train_data, maxlen = max_len) # ADDED 
test_data = pad_sequences(test_data, maxlen= max_len) # added

#*train_data = np.reshape(train_data, (train_data.shape[0], train_data.shape[1], 1))
#*test_data = np.reshape(test_data, (test_data.shape[0], test_data.shape[1], 1)) 

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, nb_classes )# ADDED
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels, nb_classes )# ADDED

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(nb_features, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout =0.2, recurrent_dropout =0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sgd'))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))

'''model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(max_len, nb_features)))#train_datalen(train_data)
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer="one")) #train_data#train_data.values.shape[1]#input_shape=(max_len,1)
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer="one"))
#model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))
#model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
'''
model.summary()
#RMSprop() 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer= 'adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit model


model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=2, batch_size=16, validation_data=(test_data, test_labels)) #validation_data=(x_test, y_test) 
score = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels,batch_size=16 ) # verbose=0
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

This code runs close to the last sequences but stops showing this error:

> indices[2,219] = 5849 is not in [0, 5849)
>
> [[Node: embedding_1/GatherV2 = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32,
>   Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read,
>   embedding_1/Cast, lstm_1/TensorArrayUnstack/range/start)]]
>
> Caused by op 'embedding_1/GatherV2', defined at:
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_launcher.py", line 78, in
>
> ```
> vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_debugger.py", line 2483, in debug
>
> ```
> exec_file(file, globals_obj)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 111, in exec_file
>
> ```
> exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 87, in exec_code
>
> ```
> exec(code_obj, global_variables)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\umroot\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\deepLearning\deepLearning\deepLearning.py", line 58, in
>
> ```
> model.add(Embedding(nb_features, 128))
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py",
>   line 497, in add
>
> ```
> layer(x)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py",
>   line 619, in **call**
>
> ```
> output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\embeddings.py",
>   line 138, in call
>
> ```
> out = K.gather(self.embeddings, inputs)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 1215, in gather
>
> ```
> return tf.gather(reference, indices)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py",
>   line 2736, in gather
>
> ```
> return gen_array_ops.gather_v2(params, indices, axis, name=name)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 3668, in gather_v2
>
> ```
> "GatherV2", params=params, indices=indices, axis=axis, name=name)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>
> ```
> op_def=op_def)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 3392, in create_op
>
> ```
> op_def=op_def)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\umroot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1718, in **init**
>
> ```
> self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> ```
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[2,219] = 5849
>   is not in [0, 5849)
>
> [[Node: embedding_1/GatherV2 = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32,
>   Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read,
>   embedding_1/Cast, lstm_1/TensorArrayUnstack/range/start)]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, it's just that you are trying every combination it seems until works without thinking about what the values are. Here are 2 changes that would aid your problem:

1. It should be `Embedding(nb_features+1, ..., input_length=max_len)` because you count number of unique indices but don't take into account the padding which is also a symbol. So you try to index 5849 a tensor of size 5849 which is the error. From the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/), "maximum integer index + 1" for `input_dim`.
2. A simplification you can do to avoid calling `to_categorical` is simply change the `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` which expects integer labels and does the one-hot encoding for you.

Comment: I changed the embdedding to : model.add(Embedding(nb_features+1, input_length = max_len, output_dim = 128)) since asked for output_dim as well. Remove the to_categorical and change the loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'.  It came up with same error again.

Comment: and what about the masking layer you mentioned before?

Comment: The masking you can use `mask_zero=True` in the Embedding layer. For the error check `np.max(data)` I'm guessing you have higher indices than unique features.

Comment: 'np.max(data)' outputs is :['990', '982', '983', '991', '446', '992', '993', '381', '994', '382', '552', '422', '385', '383', '386', '386', '386', '386', '387', '388', '389', '390', '391', '392', '392', '392', '534', '394', '393', '395', '396', '397', '397', '398', '399', '17', '253']

Comment: I think the problem is that when reads files line by line and then split them saves them in a list. So at the end 'data' is an array of lists. When nb_features= len(np.unique(data)) finds the unique values in each list and then counts the total. In this case there could be same value in 2 different lists. That is causing the issue.

How I can have array instead of array(list([...],[..],..)) for data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that integers in sequences should map to sequentially ordered ones. For example sequence "10 12 1 9 5 1 9" has 5 unique integers. But for Embedding layer, this sequence must be changed to something like "1 2 3 4 5 3 4" to be compatible with the input (vocab/feature size).

By converting sequences in my dataset and giving the maximum appearing integer as nb_features, I solved my problem

Comment: So the word-> integer mapping should be re-mapped to word->integer->embedding_integer , and use the latter as the embedding layer inputs?